# ActiveX won't run from server

Tags: javascript, activex

I have a MFC activeX that runs fine from disk but when I put it on a server I get errors.
Client: WIN7 machine
Server: Ubunto running apache

The HTML and the errors are below, please advice.
10xs,
Nahum

HTML:

```
<html>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>myFirstOCX.CAB</TITLE>
<script type="text/javascript" FOR="window">
function fn()
{
     try{
    document.all('Ctrl1').AboutBox();//error: object doesn't support propert
                                                  //or method AboutBox() 
        //OR
        var obj = new ActiveXObject ("activex.activexCtrl");
        obj.AboutBox ();//error: Automation server can't create object
       }

     catch (ex) { alert("Error: "  + ex.message); }

}
</script>
</HEAD>
<body bgcolor=lightblue >
<TABLE BORDER>
<TR>
<TD><OBJECT
 CLASSID="CLSID:E228C560-FA68-48E6-850F-B1167515C920"
 CODEBASE="./nsip.CAB#version=1,0,0,1"
 ID="Ctrl1"
 name="Ctrl1">
 </OBJECT>
 </TD>
 </TR>
 <TR>
 <TD ALIGN="CENTER">
  <INPUT TYPE=BUTTON VALUE="Click Me" onclick="fn()" >
 </TD>     </TR>      </TABLE> 
 <INPUT TYPE=TEXT ID="ConnectionString" VALUE="" >
 </body>
  </html>
```

---

the inf file
    [version] 
    ; version signature (same for both NT and Win95) do not remove
    signature="$CHICAGO$"
    AdvancedINF=2.0

```
[Add.Code]
nsip_ax_10.ocx=nsip_ax_10.ocx
nsip_ax_10.inf=nsip_ax_10.inf

[nsip_ax_10.ocx]
file=thiscab
clsid={E228C560-FA68-48E6-850F-B1167515C920}
RegisterServer=yes
FileVersion=1,0,0,1
```

Answer (score 0):

URIs use `/` characters where local Windows file systems use `\` characters.

It is usually a good idea to check the error and access logs for your web server. You should have seen the 404 error reported there.

(You might have additional problems relating to differing security zones, but that's the first one you'll stumble across).

Comment: Thanks Quentin. I changed code base to ./ and even tried server_address/nsip.CAB and just nsip.CAB - same errors. regarding the error logs of the server - there are errors but it only indicate the date, method(GET) and the address from which it came.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set the mime type for .cab files on your server (apache?) check the following for the correct mime type to set:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabinet_(file_format)

Comment: 10xs Christopher. I added AddType application/vnd.ms-cab-compressed .cab to mime.conf and restarted the server - same errors

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the inf file? edit the question to include it

Comment: I did some debugging and activeX is created - the problem is really in that method. maybe I'll try posting new question

Comment: Could be IE security preventing the control from being instantiated. Could also be a 32bit control running on a 64-bit browser and not behaving properly as a result.